# pdflatex: an empty page appears first when include a large figure

Tags: graphics, floats

Here is my simple code. The figure is 11in x 8.5in. (or in letter size). My purpose is to emerge these pdf figures together and generate pdf with bookmarks. But the first empty page is very annoying. Is there any way to remove it without compromising the figure size?

```
\documentclass[landscape,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{color,graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\textheight=11in
\clearpage
\begin{figure}[H]
 \begin{center}
 \includegraphics[width=11in]{tmpplotraw00.pdf}
 \end{center}
 \caption{core 0, Av=0}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

My output is :

```
This is pdfTeXk, Version 3.141592-1.40.3 (Web2C 7.5.6)
%&-line parsing enabled.
entering extended mode
(./tmplatex.tex
LaTeX2e <2005/12/01>
Babel <v3.8h> and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang, noh
yphenation, arabic, basque, bulgarian, coptic, welsh, czech, slovak, german, ng
erman, danish, esperanto, spanish, catalan, galician, estonian, farsi, finnish,
french, greek, monogreek, ancientgreek, croatian, hungarian, interlingua, ibyc
us, indonesian, icelandic, italian, latin, mongolian, dutch, norsk, polish, por
tuguese, pinyin, romanian, russian, slovenian, uppersorbian, serbian, swedish,
turkish, ukenglish, ukrainian, loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2005/09/16 v1.4f Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/config/color.cfg)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/config/graphics.cfg)))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/float/float.sty) (tmp/tmplatex.aux)
<tmpplotraw00.pdf, id=1, 831.105pt x 578.16pt> <use tmpplotraw00.pdf>
Overfull \hbox (449.96999pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 13--14[]
[1] [2{/usr/share/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map} <./tmpplotraw00.pdf>]            
(tmp/tmplatex.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information)</usr/share/texmf/fonts/typ
e1/bluesky/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on tmp/tmplatex.pdf (2 pages, 114822 bytes).
Transcript written on tmp/tmplatex.log.
```

Comment: So are you attempting to obtain an outcome of a single landscape page that contains an external image with a caption? If the image size if 11in x 8.5in, what should the page/stock size be? Also 11in x 8.5in - exactly the same as the image?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9710891/pdflatex-an-empty-page-appears-first-when-include-a-large-figure?noredirect=1) was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Related question, [errors - Blank pages getting inserted between figures - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286037/blank-pages-getting-inserted-between-figures)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please check *any* documentation you have on LaTeX on the meaning of `Overfull \hbox`.

Most likely your image is too large for one page, so LaTeX moves it to the second page.
Try this:

```
\includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth,height=.9\textheight,keepaspectratio]{tmpplotraw00}
```

Oh, and you really want to read `l2tabu-en`.