# Remove a blank page after the title page

Tags: article

I am using `\documentclass{article}`. The second page is `blank`, and i want to remove it.

To view the project, please use this link: https://www.overleaf.com/read/ymqqkhsxymyz

Appreciate any answers.

Comment: Please don't use external links, this question and its answers will be archived forever but will be meaningless if that project changes. Make a small example and add it as a code block to the question.

Comment: That said, look in your log `Overfull \vbox (141.74388pt too high) has occurred while \output `  the image is simply too large to fit on a page (and latex forces a page break while trying to make it fit) scale the image so that it fits

Comment: Hi @sander, I have found a discussion that may help you: 
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48114/pdflatex-an-empty-page-appears-first-when-include-a-large-figure